# Open file into array of bits in C++

Tags: c++, file, binary

I am trying to open a file into an array of bits (0,1) in C++. Every example I have seen has been working with has bytes, but I really need the actual bits. Is there an easy way to do this? The file will be <100 kB.

Comment: `std::bitset` might help you.

Comment: You could use bitmasking to extract every bit from each byte you read.

Comment: @chris: Not really. He would still have to read a file byte by byte, and I don't see convenient conversion to `bitset` from there.

Comment: Will this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708114/convert-byte-array-into-bitset

Comment: I current accept text input from the terminal for the program and use bitset for that, but I would like to be able to accept a file (not necessarily text) instead of terminal input.

Comment: What's the difference? Bytes from string or bytes from file are still bytes. Just read them and accommodate them into `bitset` properly, as already provided in the link.

Comment: Some context would help here... bytes are made of bits, you have the bytes you have the bits, bits will be stored in bytes no matter what you try. If you want to get the bits mask the byte.

Comment: What does the file itself look like ? Is it raw binary or an encoding of some sort ? I would probably design it along the lines of  vector<bool> and use a generic copy() from ifstream to vector<bool> ...

Comment: the file will most likely be an image. Basically I want to open the file, convert it to binary, do some DSP so I can transmit it wirelessly, then receive and open the image. This works with text, but I want to be able to read a file in.

Comment: There is no primitive "array of bits" construct in C/C++.  You can either use a struct/class or do your own bit twiddling.

Comment: (And if it's an image file it's almost certainly viewed as an array of bytes, not bits.)

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with `std::bitset` is you have to template the size.  You can just read it in manually though...

```
char c;
vector<char> bytes;
int nread = 0;

while( in.get(c) )
{
    if( nread == 0 ) bytes.push_back(0);
    bytes.back() = (bytes.back() << 1) | (c ? 1 : 0);
    nread = (nread + 1) % 8;
}
```

Comment: On reflection, I may have misunderstood your intent.  It seemed like you had a file of 0/1 values that you wanted to read into bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cinttypes>

namespace my
{
    template<size_t S> 
    std::istream &operator >> (std::istream &is, std::bitset<S> &bits)
    {
        std::uint8_t byte;
        size_t i = 0;
        while(i < S && (is >> byte))
            for(size_t j = 0; j < 8 && i < S; ++j)
                bits[i++] = (byte >> j) & 1;
        return is;
    }
}

int main()
{

    constexpr size_t bytes = 2;
    std::string bit_string("\x00\xFF", bytes);
    std::istringstream bit_stream(bit_string);

    std::bitset<8 * bytes> b;

    {
        using namespace my;
        bit_stream >> b;
    }

    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << b[i];

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

#### output:

```
1111111100000000
0000000011111111
```

#### run live:

http://ideone.com/Is7xRy

#### notes:

- `bitset` size is a non-type template parameter. You can't set it at runtime. So, this will only work with preallocation of the bitset and you'll get 0 padding for a larger bitset.
- If you want a runtime sized bitset, check out [boost::dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).
- The sample is expected to work for files just by replacing `istringstream` by `ifstream` appropriately .