# uint8_t element assignment to uint8_t array in C++

Tags: c++, uint8t, uint8array

I am trying to create a `uint8_t` array and try to change the first element of the array, then print it to the terminal as a string.

But, after I assign `currBlock` (changed block) to `arr[0]`, `cout` gives an error. I tried to find the answer in StackOverflow but couldn't find a similar question. Can you help me with it?

> Error: bitset::_M_copy_from_ptr

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <bitset>
    
int main()
{
    uint8_t arr[3]{0};
    uint8_t currBlock{arr[0]};
    int flag{1};
    currBlock ^= (-flag ^ arr[0]) & (1UL << 3);
    cout << "Buffer is : " << bitset<24>(arr).to_string() << endl;
    arr[0] = currBlock;
    cout << "Buffer is : " << bitset<24>(arr).to_string() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting a print out of the `uint8_t`, but instead I get an error.

Comment: You should usually share the error message you received, as it can provide many clues as to what is happening.

Comment: `I got an error` First step is to read the error message.

Comment: Is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/vaas9YeWG) the error?

Comment: Runtime error. Bitset is expecting a null-terminated string of 1s and 0s. You're not giving it one. Even before reading the error message you should [read the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset)

Comment: There is no quick and easy way to do this, though I think there should be, so [here's some suggestions ho how to get this done right.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/708114/4581301)

Comment: I never realized before now that bitset doesn't expose iterators

Comment: @MikelF this was the error message. Error message is not that big

Comment: I found a solution by iterating the array and assigning each element to new uint8_t and printing that one to terminal. It doesn't give error in this way, but it's weird